# PHP Proxy: Pass Thru HTTP Response Headers from HLS Streaming Server

Tags: php, proxy, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to proxy calls to an HTTP Live Streaming Server (lighttpd) through a PHP proxy.  However, it does not appear that the headers being returned from the streaming server are being passed back to the client.  Because of this, the video content isn't actually being streamed back to the client when going through my proxy (it's as if the client is still waiting for the entire file to be sent).

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?  Are there any open source PHP Proxies that can handle proxying streaming content?

Thanks!